State updates with incorrect data after multiple Async calls
I'm developing a React Native app and facing an issue where state variables are being set incorrectly after multiple asynchronous function calls inside useCallback. Specifically, when I navigate quickly between tabs, sometimes tipPostList gets filled with data intended for freePostList, while freePostList remains correct.
CommunityPage.jsx
const [tipPostList, setTipPostList] = useState([]);
const [freePostList, setFreePostList] = useState([]);

useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const [responseTip, responseFree] = await Promise.all([
          getPostsByType("TIP"),
          getPostsByType("FREE"),
        ]);
        setTipPostList(responseTip.data.slice(0, 3));
        setFreePostList(responseFree.data.slice(0, 3));
      } catch (error) {
        Sentry.captureException(error);
      }
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []),
);

api.js
// .... axios creation and others...

export const getPostsByType = (type) => {
  return api.get("/posts", {
    params: {
      type,
    },
  });
};

I checked the request in Postman and seems backend returns the consistent results.
What seems to be the problem here? I didn't write any code for setting tipPostList with freePostList.

Hi, As long as the parameters to the two functions are not changing from one mount to another, both apis should return the same respective result, no matter how many times the component has been remounted. There can be inconsistent state update in case there are data fetch  with varying search conditions in frequent intervals, however writing data for one state to another seems like a very isolated case.

Ensure your requests are only relevant to current screen.
use a flag to check whether component is still mounted, you simply avoid updating the state if check is false.
Thus, the state update happens only if the component is still in focus, preventing incorrect updates when navigating quickly between tabs.
const [tipPostList, setTipPostList] = useState([]);
const [freePostList, setFreePostList] = useState([]);

    useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(() => {
    let isMounted = true; // Define a flag to track if the component is still mounted
    
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const responseTip = await getPostsByType("TIP");
        const responseFree = await getPostsByType("FREE");
        
        if (isMounted) { // Only update state if the component is still mounted
          if (responseTip?.data?.length > 0) setTipPostList(responseTip.data.slice(0, 3));
          
          if (responseFree?.data?.length > 0) setFreePostList(responseFree.data.slice(0, 3));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchPosts();

    // Cleanup function to set isMounted to false when unmounting or losing focus
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []),
);

